# Magento Wishlist - Remove item

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I've built a custom script to add and remove items to the wishlist using AJAX. Adding products is not a problem but I can't figure out how to remove an item. The Magento version  is `1.5.1.0`.

The script is in `/scripts/` and looks like this:

```
include_once '../app/Mage.php';

Mage::app();

try{
    $type = (!isset($_GET['type']))? 'add': $_GET['type'];
    $id = (!isset($_GET['id']))? '': $_GET['id'];

    $session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));
    $_customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();

    if ($type != 'remove') $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);

    $wishlist = Mage::helper('wishlist')->getWishlist();

    if ($id == '')
        exit;

    if ($type == 'add')
        $wishlist->addNewItem($product);
    elseif ($type == 'remove')
        $wishlist->updateItem($id,null,array('qty' => 0));

    $products = Mage::helper('wishlist')->getItemCount();
    if ($type == 'add') $products++;
    if ($type == 'remove') $products--;

    $result = array(
        'result' => 'success',
        'type' => $type,
        'products' => $products,
        'id' => $id
    );

    echo json_encode($result);
} 
catch (Exception $e) 
{
    $result = array( 
    'result' => 'error',
        'message' => $e->getMessage()
    );
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

So when I request the script with "remove" as `$type` and the wishlist item id as $id I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getData() on a non-object in /[magento path]/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product.php on line 389
```

When I look at the function `updateItem()` in `/app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Model/Wishlist.php` it expects a "buyRequest", but I can't figure out what that is.

Comment: To remove product from wishlist using Ajax in Magento, I have created a custom function.For more details refer: http://prasadoturkar.blogspot.in/2013/06/addremove-product-from-wishlist-using.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no time to debug whatever goes wrong with your code, but using the normal convention of deleting entities should work:

```
Mage::getModel('wishlist/item')->load($id)->delete();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just have a look at the `removeAction` of `Mage_Wishlist_IndexController`.
You have to load the Wishlist item by its ID and then you can call the `delete()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but since I just ran into the same problem with magento 1.7.0.2 I want to share the solution.

To make it work you need to use the method updateItem as follow

```
$wishlist->updateItem($id, array('qty' => 10));
```

Instead of

```
$wishlist->updateItem($id, null, array('qty' => 10));
```

You can't use this method to set an item qty to 0. It will automatically set it to a minimum of 1 unless you use the delete method.

Answer (score 0):

Hi use this code to remove a product having productid `$productId` of a customer having customerid `$customerId`.

```
$itemCollection = Mage::getModel('wishlist/item')->getCollection()
    ->addCustomerIdFilter($customerId);
foreach($itemCollection as $item) {
    if($item->getProduct()->getId() == $productId){
        $item->delete();
    }
}
```