# Load wishlist items via ajax (external script)

Tags: ajax, magento, categories

Related to the post below I need to load all items which are in the wishlist via ajax once the document is ready. I've created an external script which I call via jQuery but I do not get any results. Something like...

```
include_once '../app/Mage.php';
 Mage::app();
```

I already tried several snippets to load the wishlist items in an array but I never got a result. I used to load the information with php first but we use a fullpage caching extension and I need to update the heart icons in the category view.

[image: Example from our catalog view]

Does anyone know how to get the result?

[Magento Wishlist - Remove item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145208/magento-wishlist-remove-item)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the code below. i've tested under magento 1.9 and works like a charm

```
<?php

// result buffer
$result = array();

// init magento
require_once('app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app('default');

// init session
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));

// get wishlist if logged in
if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {

    $wishList = Mage::getSingleton('wishlist/wishlist')->loadByCustomer($session->getCustomer());
    $wishListItemCollection = $wishList->getItemCollection();

    foreach ($wishListItemCollection as $item)
    {
        $result[] = array(
            'name' => $item->getName(),
            'id' => $item->getId(),
            'price' => $item->getPrice(),
            'qty' => $item->getQty()
        );

    }
}

// return
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-Type: application/json');

echo json_encode($result);
```